# how to set user privileges in array using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to set user previleges in array using codeigniter. for example i have a controller name prospect and its method. I have to check if the logged in user have permission to access these controller methods. how to check anyone please give me advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission to access these controller/methods in **constructor** of the controller.

See the example:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $session_user = $this->session->userdata('session_array');
    $method = $this->router->fetch_method();

    if(empty($session_user) && $method != 'login'){
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
  }

  public function login(){
   // Login method
  }

 public function index(){
   // home page method
  }
}
```

Here you can only access the function `login` from the controller `admin`. If you access the other functions it redirects to `login` method of `admin` controller if the session is not present.

Comment: Already i'm using ion authentication. i would like to handle for example function add(){ if($this->session->user_group('recruit'){ echo "Not allow"; }  } i have to store all those permission in an array $array = array("1"=>"recruit","2"=>"manager")